# Continuity on Metric Spaces - Equivalence with continuity and closed subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to solve the following problem involving metric spaces:

> Show in two different ways that a map $T$ from one metric space $(X, d_x)$ to another metric space $(Y, d_y)$ is continuous if and only if the inverse image of any closed set of $Y$ is a closed set of $X$.

Let's go to what I did.

**First form:** Let $F$ be nonempty and $F$ closed in $Y$. Then $B = Y \backslash F$ is opened in $Y$. Then the inverse image $T^{-1} (B)$ is opened in $X$. Thus, the inverse image $T ^ {-1} (F)$ is closed in $X$ as we wanted.

**Second form:** Suppose by absurdity that there is some closed $F$ contained in $Y$ such that $T^{-1} (F)$ is not closed in $X$. Then there is some sequence of points $x_n \in T^{-1} (F)$ with $x_n$ converging to $x$ and $x \notin  T^{-1} (F)$. Now, we know that $T_n$ are elements of $F$ and using the continuity of $T$, it follows that $T_n$ converges to $T_x$. This is an absurd.

$\color{blue}{\textrm{The converse:}}$

**First Form:** Suppose by absurdity that $T$ is not continuous. Then there is some open $B \in Y$ such that $T^{-1} (B)$ is not open in $X$.
For this $B$, we know that $F = Y \backslash B$ is closed in $Y$. Then by hypothesis $T^{-1} (F)$ is closed in $X$. Then $T^{-1} (B)$ is opened (which is an absurd).

**Second Form:** I need your help! I've tried some ways and I could not to prove another one. I have searched here and internet some solutions about this statement, but nothing has two differents ways of proof.

Comment: Friends, I got a solution. I can do it after to thought 3 days!

Comment: But I don't know if I delete this question or not. And I can't to end this question too.